# Need Suggestion on How to get data from SharePoint Online for Windows 8.1 App

Tags: sharepoint-2013, winapp

I recently working on a Windows 8.1 App, which was developed with C# and XAML. SharePoint Online is used for Data store.

I searched and found that Wictor solution can be used for Authentication. but the problem is that we can not use Wictor solution [http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx] directly as it is built upon .Net framework and Metro Apps are built upon .NetCore.

One possible option is to use WCF service and have whole Wictor solution in WCF service then call WCF service from Windows App. I tested it and it is working fine.

However, I wanted to know what would be the best approach available if I don't want to deploy this WCF separately. In future I have to publish this Win App on Windows store.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Also Is there any why we can Authenticate with SharePoint Online Without Using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RunTime? If no Than It mean we can not authenticate Window 8.1 Apps without having WCF solution which will have Wictor kind Solution.

Comment: Hello, Anyone here to answer?

Comment: [Solved] - http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/744290/Need-Suggestion-on-How-to-get-data-from-SharePoint

Comment: you can use Rest Calls for just about everything you can do with the Client Object Model. Then you don't need any Microsoft.SharePoint.Client dll's

Comment: Please try this link. It worked in my case using [this link] (https://nicolaspeters.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/using-csom-in-a-windows-8-app-for-sharepoint-online/)